# How to capture some values using xml-rs (if it's possible)

Tags: xml, rust, xml-rs

I'm using [xml-rs 0.4](https://crates.io/crates/xml-rs) and I need to capture several fields and values:

- name
- "visible"
- True

From this sample XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="rsTest+" version="1.00"/>
  <object class="rsTestWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
  </object>
</interface>
```

After looking at the xml-rs code in Github, I was able to capture `name` and `"visible"`:

```
for att in attributes {
    // test
    let temp_name_local_name = att.name.local_name.clone();
    let temp_value= att.value.clone();

    println!("{}+{}+{}", temp_name_local_name, temp_value);
}
```

Stdout:

```
name+visible
```

I could not figure out how to capture `True`.

This is my complete code:

```
extern crate xml;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

use xml::reader::{EventReader, XmlEvent};
use xml::name::{Name, OwnedName};

fn indent(size: usize) -> String {
    const INDENT: &'static str = "    ";
    (0..size)
        .map(|_| INDENT)
        .fold(String::with_capacity(size * INDENT.len()), |r, s| r + s)
}

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("./src/sample.xml").unwrap();
    let file = BufReader::new(file);

    let parser = EventReader::new(file);
    let mut depth = 0;

    for e in parser {
        match e {
            Ok(XmlEvent::StartElement {
                   name,
                   attributes,
                   namespace,
               }) => {

                /* //test
                    let n: xml::namespace::Namespace = namespace;

                    if n.is_empty() {
                        println!("empty");
                    }else{
                        println!("no empty");
                    }
                    */

                let t: String = name.local_name;
                println!("{}", t);

                if name.prefix.is_some() == true {
                    println!("{}", name.prefix.clone().unwrap().clone());
                }
                if name.namespace.is_some() == true {
                    println!("{}", name.namespace.unwrap().clone());
                }

                if attributes.is_empty() == true {
                    //"test".to_string()
                } else {

                    for att in attributes {

                        //let tet: xml::name::OwnedName = att.name;
                        let temp_name_local_name = att.name.local_name.clone();
                        let temp_value = att.value.clone();

                        println!("{}+{}", temp_name_local_name, temp_value);

                        /* //test
                            if att.name.namespace.is_some() == true {
                                 println!("{}", att.name.namespace.unwrap().clone());
                            }
                            if att.name.prefix.is_some() == true {
                                 println!("{}", att.name.prefix.unwrap().clone());
                            }
                            */
                    }
                }
                depth += 1;
            }
            Ok(XmlEvent::ProcessingInstruction { name, data }) => {
                /* //test
                    if data.is_some() == true {
                        println!("{}", data.unwrap().clone());
                    }
                    println!("{}", name );
                    */
            }
            Ok(XmlEvent::EndElement { name }) => {
                //println!("{}-{}", indent(depth), name);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                //println!("Error: {}", e);
                break;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

And my dependencies in Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
xml-rs = "0.4"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `xml-rs` is a pull parser, each structural part of an XML element is captured by multiple events, in this case of type [`XmlEvent`](https://docs.rs/xml-rs/0.4.1/xml/reader/enum.XmlEvent.html). Namely, `XmlEvent::StartElement` is triggered after parsing an opening (or bodiless) XML tag, and provides the element's name, namespace and list of attributes.
On the other hand, `XmlEvent::Characters` captures text between XML tags. This is the event that is missing in your pattern matching.

In your case, this means that you must keep track of the last entered element in order to assign that text to the entry. One possible solution is to keep a mutable record and use it at the end of an element, where it will be complete.

```
let mut record = MyStruct { /* ... */ };

for e in parser {
    match e {
        Ok(XmlEvent::StartElement { name, attributes, namespace }) => {
           record.name = name; 
           // ...
        }
        Ok(XmlEvent::Characters(text)) => {
            record.value = text; // or something else
        }
        Ok(XmlEvent::EndElement { .. }) => {
           // record is finished, use it or save it here
           // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ideally, you could build your own iterator type that abstracts `XMLEvent` away, and provides iteration over complete records. Here's an [example](https://github.com/Enet4/dicom-rs/blob/b13c13facf5ddcedce92344f86c334109f958aa6/dictionary_builder/main.rs#L141) from one of my projects.